# Javascript - 2 images appearing in codepen demo

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a demo in codepen using particle-slider. For some reason I keep getting 2 images showing when I'm only using one link. Can't for the life of me work out why. Can anyone else see why this is happening? I'm using an external link to the nextParticle js file. Here's the [link](https://codepen.io/MikeWhitehead/pen/vpGVOE/)

**index.html**

```
<img id="logo" class="next-particle"  
   data-init-position="random"
   data-init-direction="left"
   data-fade-position="left"
   data-fade-direction="left"
   data-particle-gap="1"
   data-mouse-force="80"
   data-gravity="0.08"
   data-noise="30"
   src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509810511/XBD-150x150_grl5cl.png">
```

**javascript**

```
nextParticle = new NextParticle(document.all.logo);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://nextparticle.nextco.de/documentation.html) states:

> Every `img` tag with the class `next-particle` will be automatically
>   initialized with the NextParticle script.

So when you do `nextParticle = new NextParticle(document.all.logo);` you're instantiating it again. Just skip that.

**[codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MryPQP)**

Or do the opposite and instantiate the script on your image with `nextParticle = new NextParticle(document.all.logo);` but remove the `next-particle` class

**[codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xpVyYv)**

Comment: @j96691, is there anyway to actually load a second image into nextparticle and have the particles from the first image move to draw the second image?